# converting submitted form data in codeigniter using inflector helper

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a codeigniter form which runs some basic validation and submits data to the database. But I want to additionally alter the post data of one of the fields to use the inflector helper in order to convert the posted data to camel case before submitting to the database. How do I do this?

Here is my current form:

```
<?php echo form_open('instances/create') ?>

    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea name="content"></textarea><br />


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" />

</form>
```

Here is my current controller:

```
public function create(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('inflector');

    $data['title'] = 'Create an instance';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');

    //want to camelize the 'title' here

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('instances/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
    else
    {
        $this->instances_model->set_instances();
        $this->load->view('instances/success');
    }
}
```

and here's my model:

```
<?php
class Instances_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_instances($slug = FALSE){
        if ($slug === FALSE){
            $query = $this->db->get('extra_instances');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('extra_instances', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function set_instances(){
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'slug' => $slug,
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
            'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
            'credit' => $this->input->post('credit'),
            'source' => $this->input->post('source')
        );

        return $this->db->insert('extra_instances', $data);
    }
}
```

I know that you can camelize a variable with the following:

```
echo camelize('my_dog_spot'); // Prints 'myDogSpot'
```

and I know that you can run custom validation like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

public function username_check($str)
        {
                if ($str == 'test')
                {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
                        return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }
```

But I'm lacking the knowledge of how to put this altogether to quickly change the POST data before submitting to the database.

Comment: I don't see that part of your code where you actually store the data, have you done that?

Comment: sorry - added the model to the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing too complicated, you can do it after you pass the validation, just before inserting your `data` array into the database:

```
$data = array(
    'slug' => $slug,
    'title' => camelize($this->input->post('title')),
    // ...
```